# How best to display a list of items as a popup that gets sized correctly in ExtJS 6

Tags: extjs

I have a list of errors (between 1 and 20 in the list).  I want to create a popup window that shows the list and is sized to contain it reasonably well regardless of the users font or browser.  I made an example in sencha's fiddle here that shows my issue and my non optimal solution.  Please suggest how to improve (or use some other mechanism in sencha to get what I want).

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/18ef

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {

        var errorTpl = new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl for=".">', '<ul class="thumb-wrap">', '<li><b>{Message}</b></li>', '</ul>', '</tpl>');

        var errorView = Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
            layout: 'fit',
            // data: errorList,
            data: [{
                Message: '1 alsfdjaslfkjas;fljksafjsakflsalfjsalf;safsa;lfsal;dfsalfd'
            }, {
                Message: '2 alsfdjaslfkjas;fljksafjsakflsalfjsalf;safsa;lfsal;dfsalfd'
            }, {
                Message: '3 alsfdjaslfkjas;fljksafjsakflsalfjsalf;safsa;lfsal;dfsalfd'
            }, {
                Message: '4 alsfdjaslfkjas;fljksafjsakflsalfjsalf;safsa;lfsal;dfsalfd'
            }, {
                Message: '5 alsfdjaslfkjas;fljksafjsakflsalfjsalf;safsa;lfsal;dfsalfd'
            }, {
                Message: '6 alsfdjaslfkjas;fljksafjsakflsalfjsalf;safsa;lfsal;dfsalfd'
            }, {
                Message: '7 alsfdjasl alsfdjasl alsfdjasl fkjas;fljksafjsakflsalfjsalf;safsa;lfsal;dfsalfd'
            }],
            tpl: errorTpl,
            itemSelector: 'div.thumb-wrap'
        });

        var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            title: 'Problems Found (Please Correct)',
            modal: true,
            layout: 'vbox',
            width: 500,
            height: 50 + errorView.data.length * 40,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                margin: "10 10 10 10",
                text: 'close',
                listeners: {
                    click: function() {
                        this.up('window').close();
                    }
                }
            },
            errorView]
        }).show();
    }
});
```

***UPDATE:
I did this and it seems to help a lot

```
var htmlError = errorTpl.apply(errorList);
Ext.Msg.alert('Problems Found (Please Correct)',htmlError);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't set the height of the window.

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/18ej